# Access Models from OUTSIDE rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jrubyonrails

I am writing a JRuby rails app that uses mysql-backed models.  Now, I need to update the models from OUTSIDE the app (via EventMachine / similar), so that the Controllers etc IN the rails app can get access to the fresh data.

So, is the Rails ORM available inside EventMachine? Will there be catastrophic consequences if I update the mysql tables from inside EventMachine (if the ORM is not available to me)?

Answer (score 3):

You could always `require 'config/environment.rb'`, that'll give you access to all the models.