# Rails app with non-HTTP access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, command-line

Hypothetical question (at the moment!)

Suppose I have a great idea for an application. It acts on data which can be well-represented by tables in a relational database, using interlinked objects which represent those tables. It supports a well-defined API for interacting with (Creating, Reading, Updating, Deleting) those objects, and viewing information about them.

In short, it's a perfect fit for Rails... except it doesn't want to be a web-app. Perhaps it wants a Command Line interface; or an OS-native dialog-based interface; or perhaps it wants to present itself as a resource to other apps. Whatever - it just isn't designed to present itself over HTTP.

[These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056133/access-models-from-outside-rails-app) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408426/is-rails-appropriate-for-use-with-a-non-web-centric-app) suggest it's certainly possible, but both approach the problem from the point of view of adapting an existing web-app to have an additional, non-web, interface.

I'm interested in knowing what the best way to *create* such an app would be. Would you be best to `rails new non_web_app`, in order to get the skeleton built "for free", then write some "normal" Ruby code that `require`s `config/environment` - but then you have a lot of web-centric cruft that you don't need? Or would it be better to roll up your sleeves and build it from whole cloth, taking just the libraries you need and manually writing any required configuration?

If the latter, what exactly *is* needed to make a Rails app, but without the web bits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access the Rails ORM to develop a CRUD non-web application, just include ActiveRecord in your own Ruby script; you will avoid using a lot of Rails modules you probably don't need (routing, template generator, ...) [Here is an example of how to do it](http://amolbrid.blogspot.com/2010/11/test-post.html).

If you prefer to have the full Rails stack, do not run your Rails web app in an application server (WEBrick, Passenger, Mongrel, ...) to avoid any HTTP exposure, and interact with your application using tasks or the rails console.

Comment: "Just include ActiveRecord" - fair enough, but it will also need configuration with the database details, at least. Basically, what's needed to bootstrap an AR-based CRUD app, if not going down the "start with Rails and strip bits off" route?

Comment: Please check the link now included in the answer.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that does explain it. Pretty straightforward, really.

Comment: You'll probably want to also make sure active_support is included ... that will add several conventions you're used to like .blank? (and more). It'll feel more rails-like

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid taking Rails too far off the rails. If I were doing this and felt that the gains of rails w/o the web stuff I'd do the following:

```
rails new non_web_app
```

and ignore the webbish cruft and use rails to generate models. In this way you get the tight, comfortable database behavior and can tie various gems in as you want to augment those models. I'd not bother implementing views, of course, and I'd consider implementing controllers in which the various render bits are removed and to use you instantiate an instance of the controller and call the action directly. This means the controller represents your API into your business logic still but the "views" it now "renders" are simply the return of the data output.

Then you could simply strip out the bits you do not need...the public directory, the view structure under app, config/routes.rb, etc.  You'll need to test those changes incrementally and make sure that removing some now extraneous bit doesn't throw the Rails world into chaos.

Comment: This is a good answer. A rails app that utilizes all the ORM & application bootstrapping, test lib integration, etc... but just eschews controllers and views, in favor of non-http services. It's actually a pretty good idea, there's nothing in the rules that says you _have_ to be building a website or REST API. Loads of my rails apps run subservices like pubsub listeners, no reason why you need to include anything else

Answer (score 0):

Rails is for Web apps. That means HTTP. Now, you could package a Web app so that it runs on the desktop instead, or you could use ActiveRecord with a desktop application framework like [Monkeybars](http://monkeybars.org/).